# F#: Class with no default constructor as type parameter?

Tags: f#

I have a `FileReader` class whose job is to read and process text files using a `StreamReader`. To facilitate unit testing, I'd like to provide a type parameter to this class so that I can swap the `StreamReader` for a `FakeReader` that doesn't actually interact with the file system (and maybe throws exceptions such as `OutOfMemory`, so I can test the error handling in `FileReader`).

Ideally, I'd like to define `FileReader` something like this (trivialized for clarity):

```
type FileReader<'Reader> =
    member this.Read file =
        use sr = new 'Reader(file)
        while not sr.EndOfStream do
            printfn "%s" <| sr.ReadLine()
```

and simply define `FakeReader` to have a constructor that takes the file name, the `EndOfStream` property getter, the `ReadLine()` method, and the (empty) `Dispose()` method. However, F# has several complaints about this type definition, including `"Calls to object constructors on type parameters cannot be given arguments."` Since `StreamReader` has no default constructor, this approach seems like a no-go.

So far the only way I've gotten this to work is to inherit `FakeReader` from `StreamReader`:

```
type FakeReader() =
    inherit StreamReader("") with
    override this.ReadLine() = "go away"
    member this.EndOfStream = false
    member this.Dispose() = ()
```

and use a factory method that returns either a new `FakeReader` or a new `StreamReader` as appropriate.

```
type ReaderType = Fake | SR
let readerFactory (file : string, readerType) =
    match readerType with
    | Fake -> new FakeReader() :> StreamReader
    | SR -> new StreamReader(file)

type FileReader(readertype) =
    member this.Read file =
        use sr = readerFactory(file, readertype)
        while not sr.EndOfStream do
            printfn "%s" <| sr.ReadLine()
```

This seems a lot less elegant. Is there a way to do this with a type parameter? Thanks to all.

Comment: Do you really want it to be OOP based or any other more functional approach will also work for you ?

Comment: A more functional approach would actually be great. I tend to fall back on the OOP crutch due to many years in imperative land.

Answer (score 4):

Using a function that creates a reader object (as suggested by MizardX) is the direct answer to your question. However, I'd maybe consider using a different abstraction than `TextReader`). As Ankur mentioned in a comment, you could use a more functional approach.

If you're just reading lines of text from the input using `TextReader`, you could use a `seq<string>` type instead. The `FileReader` type may actually be just a function taking `seq<string>` (although that may be oversimplification... it depends).

This makes it more "functional" - in functional programming, you're often transforming data structures using functions, which is exactly what this example does:

```
open System.IO

/// Creates a reader that reads data from a file
let readFile (file:string) = seq {
  use rdr = new StreamReader(file)
  let line = ref ""
  while (line := rdr.ReadLine(); !line <> null) do
    yield !line }

/// Your function that processes the input (provided as a sequence)
let processInput input = 
  for s in input do 
    printfn "%s" s

readFile "input.txt" |> processInput
```

To test the `processInput` function, you could then create a new `seq<string>` value. This is significantly easier than implementing a new `TextReader` class:

```
let testInput = seq {
  yield "First line"
  yield "Second line"
  raise <| new System.OutOfMemoryException() }

testInput |> processInput
```

Comment: That is indeed cleaner than reimplementing TextReader and it's good to know I wasn't missing anything obvious that would have made my type parameter approach work. Thank you as always Tomas.

Answer (score 3):

You could pass in a function that constructs and returns an object of your desired type.

```
type FileReader(f : string -> TextReader) =
    member this.Read file =
        use sr = f file
        while sr.Peek() <> -1 do
            printfn "%s" <| sr.ReadLine()

type FakeReader() =
    inherit StringReader("")
    override this.ReadLine() = "go away"
    override this.Peek() = 0

let reader1 = new FileReader(fun fn -> new StreamReader(fn) :> _)

let reader2 = new FileReader(fun fn -> new FakeReader() :> _)
```

Cast was necessary because I dropped the generic type-argument, but the actual type can be inferred.

Comment: I think the function can be just `string -> TextReader` (and you don't need the type argument), because the implementation in the `FileReader` is using just public methods of `TextReader` and doesn't use the type of the actual reader.

Comment: (Argh, stand by, trying to fix formatting.) Thank you both for your replies - if I understand correctly, you're thinking:

    type ReaderType = Fake | SR
    let readerFactory readerType (file : string) =
        match readerType with
        | Fake -> new FakeReader() :> StreamReader
        | SR -> new StreamReader(file)

    type FileReader(factory : string -> StreamReader) =
        member this.Read file =
            use sr = factory file
            while not sr.EndOfStream do
                printfn "%s" <| sr.ReadLine()

    let reader = new FileReader(readerFactory Fake)

Comment: Close; You could skip the extra type: `new FileReader(fun fn -> new StreamReader(fn))` vs `new FileReader(fun fn -> new FakeReader())`

Comment: Thank you and sorry about the messed-up formatting, as I ran out of time to edit before figuring out how to fix it.